# Does this rdists package provide actual (predicted) response time for each observation?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, software, reaction-time

With the help of other packages, I've estimated Drift Diffusion model parameters of my data. Now, I want to estimate the predicted (or actual) response times for each observation with the help of estimated parameters. By going through the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtdists/rtdists.pdf) I got a sense that `ddiffusion` function estimates (predicts) the actual response times, basically I used this code for my own purposes:

```
dd1<-ddiffusion(data$rt , data$resp,a=2.16,v=1.12,t0=0.36,z=0.51).
```

Does this function gives me actual (predicted) response time for each observation?

Answer (score 1):

Not very familiar with this package, but per manual (bold and italics added):

> *ddiffusion* gives the density, *pdiffusion* gives the distribution function, ***qdiffusion* gives the quantile function (i.e., predicted RTs)**, and *rdiffusion* generates random response times and decisions (returning a data.frame with columns rt (numeric) and response (factor)).

So, it looks like if you want predicted reaction times, you should use the qdiffusion function (but note that it is a quantile function).

Comment: mfloren, thanks for the contribution. When I run qdiffusion returns, for instance, 2.27 when the observed response time is 0.62. It doesn't make sense, as predicted RT cannot be higher than the observed RT.

Comment: @Samir The qdiffusion gives quantiles of the predicted values based off of "minimizing the absolute difference between desired probability and the value returned from pdiffusion using optimize." Have you gotten a chance to look through the examples in the documentation? That is where all of this information is coming from.

Comment: Yes, I am constantly reading the manual. Apparently, I have to spend more time on it. Thanks

Comment: @Samir You're welcome. I am not an expert of this package by any means, and perhaps others can give a more satisfactory answer. I'll update mine to include that.

Answer (score 0):

The functions estimate the parameters of the distribution. If I understand you correctly, you want to make individual predictions - these require a predictor variable in the sense of a regression model. (sorry for the late response, I just stumbled across the question)

Comment: Thanks - appreciate your contribution!